# Lock python script to read/write files

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm making a sandbox, and I wanted to block any form of file reading and writing to make it more secure.

However, I can't do it at the Python level, I want to apply it to the Qt bindings (PySide or PyQt). Not including them in the sandbox is not an option for me.

I tried or found the following:

- sys.addaudithook and PySys_AddAuditHook: It looks like Qt doesn't send an audit hook to Python, which makes sense.
- filelock: This is a library to lock files, which is cross-platform. However, it doesn't serve my purpose as it wouldn't restrict new files and it would be a lot of work for existing files.

In the original code, I use RestrictedPython, but to give an example, let's say I run the script like this:

```
 with open("script.py") as script:
     exec(script.read())
```

Is there a way to tell Python, C or Qt that I don't want files to be opened in a sandbox?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely you will be able to do that on the Python level. Run your python script within a sandbox, like a Docker container, to achieve this effect. Also don't develop your own sandbox. Never develop your own security-related software. What is your target OS? On Linux there are many established options for this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm looking for another way (like creating my own command-based mini-language, since I don't need too much functionality). The plan is to make it cross-platform, taking advantage of the use of qt, so using only linux would not work for me. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @musicamante My question is related to c. Since if there is a solution in ctypes, I want to implement it. If anyone knows c, I can translate qt code written in c to Python, even without knowing much about c. Can I add the tag again?

Comment: @DanteS. I doubt Qt would be helpful for what you want to do (you could use some of its components, but nothing it provides would be fundamental for your purpose). Besides, Qt code is written in C++, not C; and since you admit that you don't know a lot of C (and C++, I'd assume) and you would still attempt to port it into python, it would make that tag pointless anyway, especially since, as said above, it's unlikely that you'll be able to do it at Python level in any case.